# Create complex and interactive web applications

Tags: web-applications, web

*(I'm very sorry if this question is inappropriate or wrong. I'm a newbie and I have nowhere to ask. Though I have a feeling that this question will be marked as "too broad".)*

Always wondering how complex web applications are made nowadays.

For example, [GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com/), a nice web app for creating and designing UML diagrams.
Here's a screenshot from the app:
[image]

Another example, Google Docs - Spreadsheets, Documents, Presentations, etc.
Here's a screenshot from Google Spreadsheet app:
[image]

There are many questions in my head..
How these applications are made ?
Is it pure JavaScript (on client-side) ?
Is it using any frameworks (Like Zend, Yii, etc.) ?
(Tried looking at page source but can't found any clues)

Can you recommend any links, books, or anything that will help me to create one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GenMyModel, it's mainly based on [Google Web Toolkit](http://www.gwtproject.org/), or GWT for short, it is a development toolkit for building and optimizing complex browser-based applications. GWT is used by many products at Google, including Google AdWords and Google Wallet. It's open source, completely free, and used by thousands of enthusiastic developers around the world.

Regarding Google Docs, you can't actually tell, but for sure it relies extensively on JavaScript.

A better way to know more about such applications, try checking [github](http://github.com) and look for open source projects that look alike and start investigating the source code. It helps in both shaping your knowledge and create better applications!

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge on GWT, haven't heard it before until now. GWT looks great.

Comment: @topher Last time I used it was almost 6 years ago, I'm sure it has been enhanced enormously. give it try, and you can mark the question answered if this answer satisfied you.

Comment: Whoa.. 6 years is a long time :D ... I also found another framework called [Vaadin](http://vaadin.com), I think it is very similar to GWT. Hmm.. Still curious about Google's stuff, though. :)